# Spring JTA supported by MONGODB

Tags: spring, mongodb, transactions, spring-data-jpa, jta

In my application I need to store some data to the `RDBMS` DB and some data to the `MongoDB` in the same transaction and I am using `Spring JTA` for my `RDBMS` transactions.

I am new to `MongoDB` and i am not sure that will this `Spring JTA` supported by `MongoDB`. What's the way or api to handle a transaction programmaticaly in `MongoDB` as `MongoDB` doesn't support transaction.

As like working with `RDBMS` and by annotating a method `@Transactional`, all operation's in method done as a single atomic operations and if an error occur automatic rollback done by `Spring JTA` but how we can achieve this using `MongoDB`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atomic operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) or [two-phase commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). Also Check [this](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/04/mongodb-multi-statement-transactions-yes-we-can/) out. This article explains about plugin developed for `Mongo` that promises not only `transactions` but also a boosting in performance.

Comment: I referred to http://www.tokutek.com/2013/04/mongodb-multi-statement-transactions-yes-we-can/  document but i am unable to run beginTransaction and rollbackTransaction on my MongoDB version 3.0.1.     I am getting following error      db.runCommand({‘rollbackTransaction':1})

“ok” : 0,
“errmsg” : “no such command: rollbackTransaction”,
“code” : 59,
“bad cmd” : {
“rollbackTransaction” : 1
}

Comment: @ManojTailor Because it's part of a mongo plugin, not official.

Comment: The 2PC mentioned here is not the same thing in JTA.